# Evee triangular bad shading, tried many things it wont work

Tags: shaders, normals

[image][image]

Hello everyone, Ive been having problem with this recently, It looks great in Cycles but in evee it gives me that shading, Things I have tried;
Recalculate normal
Subdivision
Shade smooth degree modifications
remove doubles
Please let me know if you know what is the problem

Comment: hello, please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: both images are the same... did you mean to provide an Eevee and a Cycles sample for reference? Could it be related to this? https://youtu.be/yPo79bXkJOc

Comment: I found out the problem, it was the custom shading, and thanks for the link but that wasnt the issue, it was because ofthe shading not the shadows an as I was using HDRI I couldnt tweak the source light shadows directly anyway.